# Flutter Login With Facebook

Tags: flutter, dart

i have an issue with generate apk when use facebook login

im using   `flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0`

when i'm trying to generate apk i still get this :

i have done all of configuration to work with facebook login and i try  it and there's no problem but the issue come when trying to generate apk !

```
Note: /Users/abuzreaq/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_facebook_login-3.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/roughike/facebooklogin/facebooklogin/FacebookLoginPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':keyboard_visibility:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > 1 exception was raised by workers:                                 
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
     /Users/abuzreaq/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e12f293e8f097aaa63c82a5c3a8ea889/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
                                                                        
     /Users/abuzreaq/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e12f293e8f097aaa63c82a5c3a8ea889/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 10m 25s                                                 
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     629.5s
The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin flutter_facebook_login...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                   25.3s


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'facebook_login'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
```

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

It says can't find Android SDK on your project.

It sometimes happens when you update android studio or gradle.

You can set path on local.properties in Android folder

```
flutter.buildMode=release
flutter.versionName=2.0.0
flutter.sdk=C:\\src\\flutter
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
flutter.versionCode=1001
```

Comment: i have all these setting

sdk.dir=/Users/abuzreaq/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/abuzreaq/flutter
flutter.buildMode=release
flutter.versionName=1.0.2
flutter.versionCode=1